# Product in reservation show like out of stock (MAGENTO2 MSI)

Tags: magento2, addtocart, out-of-stock, manage-stock, reservations

I have `stock_qty = 2` and `salable_qty = 0` because of my products reservations and when I open product page `add To Cart` exists. Can this product show like out of stock when salable qty is 0 ?

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed the default Magento behavior, but you could alter it by adding an after plugin on `isAvailable()` method from the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` class and inside it, you could interrogate the `isSalable()` method from `Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\AreProductsSalableInterface` service (as `Magento\InventorySalesApi\Api\IsProductSalableInterface` is now marked as deprecated) to double- check if the product is really available.